# Microsoft Reporting 2005 with Visual Studio 2012 .Net 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-2.0, reporting-services, microsoft-reporting

How can I included Microsoft reporting 2005 with Visual studio 2012 while I'm working under .Net Framework 2.0?

Comment: you are  going to need to upgrade the SSRS2005 report to SSRS 2012. check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sqlreportingservices/thread/4de7983c-c895-4307-8f8b-c5a848715bf0)

Comment: But wouldn't this mean that I would also have to move to another framework?

Comment: You have to upgrade you report SSRS or you want to use SSRS 2005 then use report builder [Here MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337424(v=sql.90).aspx) to develope SSRS report.